# Cannot load modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so into server

Tags: websocket, mod-proxy, apache2.4

Recently I need integrate a websocket server with apache2，and I find that apache2.4 has supported websocket with the module : `mod_proxy_wstunnel`.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

I compiled them by myself, but encountered a problem :

`httpd: Syntax error on line 122 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_release_connection`

- environment info:
- OS:centos 6.8
- php:php-7.0.10
- apache:httpd-2.4.23

My steps are:

1. Download source code.

   - php7  github.com/php/php-src/releases/tag/php-7.0.10
   - apache2.4 github.com/apache/httpd/releases/tag/2.4.23
2. Copy to my workspace and tar，say /home

   - shell> tar -xjf php-7.0.10.tar.bz2
   - shell> tar -xjf httpd-2.4.23.tar.bz2
3. Install gcc : yum install gcc
4. Compile apache

   - down apr：`apr-1.5.2.tar.gz`    `apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz`
   - copy to `/httpd-2.4.23/srclib`
     `tar -zvf apr-1.5.2.tar.gz`     `tar -zvf apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz`
   - Modify the files name: 
     `apr-1.5.2` as `apr`   
         `apr-util-1.5.4` as `apr-util`
   - Install pcre
     `yum install pcre-devel`
   - `./configure --enable-so --enable-http --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-http --with-included-apr --enable-proxy-wstunnel`
   - make && make install
   - set apache server ip：
     shell> `vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
     ServerName 127.0.0.1
5. Compile php

   - libxml2:
     yum install libxml2-devel
   - mkdir /usr/local/php7
   - ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --with-mysqli --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
   - make && make install
   - cp -v ./php.ini-production /usr/local/php7/lib/php.ini
   - configure httpd.conf
     shell> vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
     `<FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
     </FilesMatch>`
6. enalbe mod_proxy_wstunnel
   shell> vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
   `LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so`

Above is my steps. Then I try to start my apache2 :

`/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start`

Got the following errors:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 122 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_release_connection`

I have google it , but can't find some helpful info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load mod_proxy as well as mod_proxy_wstunnel. If you load an underlying proxy module (http/fcgi/ajp/wstunnel) without mod_proxy you will get this error.

So check your configuration and make sure you have a `LoadModule` directive for mod_proxy as well as mod_proxy_wstunnel.

You can also use the output of `apachectl -M` to check the modules Apache is loading.

Comment: Thanks,my friend.That's my mistake.